# Sum $\sum_{n=0}^{N} z^n=\frac{1-z^{N+1}}{1-z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, summation

My professor just gave this as given in class today and went onto something else.

Show that 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N} z^n=\frac{1-z^{N+1}}{1-z}.$$

I would like to know how he obtained this neat expression for the sum. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried induction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $z\neq1$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N}z^{n}=\frac{1-z}{1-z}\sum_{n=0}^{N}z^{n}=\frac{1}{1-z}\sum_{n=0}^{N}(1-z)z^{n}=\frac{1}{1-z}\sum_{n=0}^{N}z^{n}-z^{n+1}=\frac{1-z^{N+1}}{1-z}$$

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it just comes from the standard factorization of 1-x^n:$$1-x^n=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+....x^{n-1})$$

Just divide both sides of the equation by 1-x and there you have it. Well, use z instead of x, and n+1 instead of n.